# Objective C: How to prevent NSURLConnection from changing class delegate instance variable?

Tags: objective-c

I've been looking around for quite awhile and I cannot seem to figure out how to solve a rather annoying error I am getting.

I have two classes:  One manages requests and NSURLConnections (only one at a time) and sends a callback to the class delegate when all is said and done (NSURLConnection finishes loading all the data).  The problem arises when the callback method is called on the delegate, I've traced the pointer and it seems that it changed its address.

How did NSURLConnection change the address of my class instance variable (id delegate)?  I never used it in any way with NSURLConnection (at least I think I didn't).

Code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JSON.h"

@interface Downloader : NSObject 
{
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    id delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

- (void)download:(NSString*)url;

- (void)finished:(id)object;

@end

#import "Downloader.h"


@implementation Downloader

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)download:(NSString*)url
{   
    //NSLog(@"The delegate is: [%@]", delegate);
    receivedData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init] retain];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self] retain];
}

- (void)finished:(id)object
{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data]; 
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    [receivedData release];

    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Downloader: Finished download");
    //NSLog(@"The delegate is: [%@]", delegate);

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] retain];
    NSString *jsonString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] retain];

    //NSLog(@"Downloader: Received [%@]", jsonString);

    // Parse the JSON into an Object
    id jsonObject = [parser objectWithString:jsonString];

    // Call the delegate and give it the JSON Object.
    [delegate finished:jsonObject];

    [connection release];
    //[receivedData release];
}

@end
```

Been spending quite a bit of time trying to figure this one out... kudos to anyone if they can find the source of this mysterious issue!

It blows up right here:

```
// Call the delegate and give it the JSON Object.
[delegate finished:jsonObject];
```

And throws this error:

Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

It used to throw an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" but since has stopped doing that...

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hoha and @Anomie are correct... I'll just point out that in Cocoa, objects never retain their delegate, since delegates may hold a reference to the object they're delegating, which can set up a retain loop if you're running w/o GC.

So you're doing everything correct when you set your delegate property to assign... but some other object (like a view controller) needs to be responsible for retaining your delegate and then releasing it when you're done with the download.

Comment: Thanks!  (Credit to everyone thus far, you guys pretty much nailed it.  It wasn't retained and it somehow got deallocated and when I called the callback method on it I got the error... now I don't.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that downloader is deallocated prematurely and this

> seems that it changed its address

makes my suspicion even stronger. Try to override `dealloc` in `Downloader` and insert logging there.

Answer (score 0):

It very much sounds like the object you assigned as the delegate has been released; that most often gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS but can give "unrecognized selector sent to instance" if a new object happens to be allocated in the exact same location as the old.